# convergence of series of function in distributions

Tags: distribution-theory

I'm trying to prove that:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} t_n(x) = -\delta'(x)$$
where

$$t_n(x) = \begin{cases}-n^2, & 0\leq x < \frac1n\\ n^2, & -\frac1n< x < 0\end{cases}$$
Help will be appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried to solve this problem? What definition of $\delta'(x)$ are you using?

Comment: I tried to use the definition of convergence of series of function in distributions

Answer (score 0):

What is nice with the distributions is that if $f_n \to \delta$ (in the **sense of distributions**) then $f_n' \to \delta'$ (where $f_n'$ is the distributional derivative, which is the usual derivative if $f_n$ is differentiable).

So integrate $t_n$ to obtain $f_n(x) = -\int_{-1}^x t_n(y)dy$ and show that $f_n \to \delta$ in the sense of distributions, ie that for any $\varphi \in C^\infty_c $ :
$$\lim_{n \to \infty } \int_{-\infty}^\infty \varphi(x) f_n(x)dx = \varphi(0)$$

Comment: Why is the lower boundary of the integral -1? thank you!

Comment: @user2600366 (compute $f_n(x) = \int_{-1}^x t_n(y)dy$) it is to make the integration constant such that $f_n$ is compactly supported

Comment: @user2600366 are you stuck somewhere ?